# How protect WordPress from being used in DDoS atack via XML-RPC

Tags: wordpress

best what I've found googling around is

```
add_filter( ‘xmlrpc_methods’, function( $methods ) {
   unset( $methods['pingback.ping'] );
   return $methods;
} );
```

Is any better solution then blocking pingback.ping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Protect WordPress from DDoS attack on Pingbacks](http://softduit.com/protect-wordpress-from-ddos-attack-on-pingbacks/):

> They also offered two solutions for stopping your WordPress website from being used to attack others.  The third one below is my suggestion.
>
> 1. Turn off / disable notifications in your WordPress admin settings
> 2. Add the following code to your functions.php file (not for novices)
>
>    ```
>    add_filter( ‘xmlrpc_methods’, function( $methods ) {
>       unset( $methods['pingback.ping'] );
>       return $methods;
>    } );
>    ```

Comment: method is exactly like in my question, I'm approving for the link with explanation. And of course it works.